# GET and POST Method in same form

Tags: php, mysql

So i want to use the GET method and POST method on the same form. The GET to send the details from the form to the url bar and the post for a isset if statement to check if the form has been submitted. I would like to be able to do this. But if you can find another way of doing it please tell me
HTML

```
<form method="post">
<p>Username:</p><input type="text" name="Username">
<p>Password:</p><input type="password" name="Password">
<p>Post:</p><input type="text" name="Post" value=""><br><input type="submit" 
value="submit" name="submited">
</form>
```

PHP

```
if (isset($_POST['submited'])){
    $Username=$_GET["Username"]; 
    $Password=$_GET["Password"]; 
    $Post=$_GET["Post"]; 
    $Password=md5($Password);

    if(blah=blah){
        echo "blah";
    }
}
```

Comment: It's really a bad idea to pass a password through url parameters. "I would like to be able to do this" --- please explain why.

Comment: You can't, those represent the HTTP method for the requests so you'd be conceivably talking about sending 2 requests which would have to be handled separately.  You should just be using POST.

Comment: You can't. The form is either POST or GET. You could use javascript to do this, but really why? As your code is now, changing your $_GET to $_POST will make it work.

Comment: @Matt Whipple: "You can't" --- actually you *can*. Just set the `action` as `post` and specify parameters as the form action. On the server the data will be parsed into `_GET` and `_POST` accordingly.

Comment: Use `post` for sending forms. Its better practice and even semantically nicer (your `posting` data, for example)...BUT, if you want to send `get` params, just put them in the form action url like: `action="/post.php?get=param"`

Comment: @zerkms, just because they're exposed to PHP variables doesn't mean that's what's happening or that it's a good idea.  It's programming by coincidence, and it's not an answer to the actual question.  And this also doesn't work in this case unless JS is dynamically updating the forms action attribute which just makes the solution even uglier.

Comment: @Matt Whipple: I didn't say it's a good idea (actually I said the opposite in my first comment). I just said that it's possible to do with php. "unless JS is dynamically updating the forms action attribute which just makes the solution even uglier" --- I didn't say the solution is elegant either, but said it's technically possible. "it's not an answer to the actual question" --- that's why I put it into the comments, not into the answers section.

Comment: @zerkms: "use the GET method and POST method on the same form" <-- This desired behavior is NOT possible.  Introducing how PHP happens to expose the request data is confusing the issue and providing no value for the OP.

Comment: @Matt Whipple: the desired behaviour is to get the data from `_POST` and `_GET` in the very same moment. Check the code. OP is just not good in expressing their thoughts (because of lack of knowledge presumably). Just get used to understanding what newbies want by reading their code, not the explanation ))

Comment: @zerkms But that's not the question that is being asked, and the way the question is asked demonstrates a lack of understanding of what is actually happening which you are encouraging if anything.  Rather than providing any form of clarity you're advocating blindly seizing a questionable implementation.

Comment: @Matt Whipple: Nope. I'm advocating using less technical details with the newbies (since it's more harm than good, they are not ready yet for that). If someone asks how much will it take to get from A to B - teach them about velocity and time, not quantum physics.

Comment: @zerkms But you'd already admitted that the solution isn't a good one...and I didn't give technical details, I just pointed in a direction that could be followed to details.

Comment: @Matt Whipple: right. I admitted it's a crap. But I didn't mention OP to get too deep into HTTP specification. At the moment I see the best thing for him is just to accept that "it's bad, mkay", just following more experienced community members advices.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
isset($_POST['submited'])
```

to

```
isset($_GET['submited'])
```

But it is a really bad idea to send password using GET.

Comment: ok why? not worried about security currently.i am just testing. But can you tell me anyway

Comment: This will transfer the password visible in clear text. And it will show up in the browsers history, server logs etc.

Answer (score 0):

Kinda bad practice, but you could force it by sending parameters in URL:

Setting like `action="index.php?data=123"` should do the work:

```
<form method="post" action="index.php?name=a&surname=b"> //Here we go
  <p>Username:</p><input type="text" name="Username">
  <p>Password:</p><input type="password" name="Password">
  <p>Post:</p><input type="text" name="Post" value="">
  <br>
  <input type="submit" value="submit" name="submited">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

in your form you can change it's action -- so action="?var1=something&var2=example"

It could be done with javascript; example:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head> 
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){ 
        $('form').submit(function() {
                $('form').attr('action','?Username=' + $('input[name=Username]').val() + '&Password=' + $('input[name=Password]').val() + '&Post=' + $('input[name=Post]').val());
                return true;
        });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post">
<p>Username:</p><input type="text" name="Username">
<p>Password:</p><input type="password" name="Password">
<p>Post:</p><input type="text" name="Post" value=""><br><input type="submit" 
value="submit" name="submited">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would POST the form to say my formprocess.php page, placing your

`if(isset($_POST['submitted'])) { 
   //Code goes here, do checks/validation etc 
   }`

Then once you've done what you needed to do with your code do a header (or meta redirect if you have already sent your headers) like so:

```
header('Location:http://www.mysite.com/index.php?value=formsubmitted&action=success');
```

So the value= and the action= could just be the values you want to pass back in the URL. You could also add some RewriteRule 's to your .htaccess to make these redirected URL's a bit prettier and better for SEO etc. Also if you do go down this route, make sure to set/define the redirection status i.e. 301 see below:

```
header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");
```

Comment: Also as mentioned above, please please, don't use GET method when inserting and/or querying any information as you've done in your example i.e. for a login form by the looks of things! One of the main reasons why NOT to do this (already mentioned above but worth repeating) is this is a perfect invitation for SQL injections and hacks, not to mentioned how unsecure it would be!

Answer (score 0):

I think what everyone is wondering is why anyone would need to use $_GET if they are using $_POST.
i.e.:

```
if (isset($_POST['submited'])){
    $Username=$_POST["Username"]; 
    $Password=$_POST["Password"]; 
    $Post=$_POST["Post"]; 
    $Password=md5($Password);

    if(blah=blah){
        echo "blah";
    }
}
```

... and if you want to check your parameters while developing just stick in...

```
print_r($_POST)
```

Is there any reason why you need to retrieve your form field data from a $_GET?